# Appending the same Option to multiple selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Hi all : quick question : I have three Select elements in my page, which I need to fill with the same options (initially). The data comes from a AJAX request.

Can somebody tell me why only the first Select has the options appended (allthough it is last in the .each()), whereas the others do not? It is not a major problem, I can solve it in other ways, but I was just curious if someone could explain this to me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            
                    var data = {test: "testing", test2: "testing2", test3: "testing3"}
                    let subscriptionSelect = $('#select1');
                    let showSelect = $('#select3');
                    let noShowSelect = $('#select4');
                    subscriptionSelect.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('------'));
                    showSelect.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('------'));
                    noShowSelect.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('------'));
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        let option = new Option(key, value);
                        noShowSelect.append(option);
                        showSelect.append(option);
                        subscriptionSelect.append(option);
                    });
                   
                },
        );
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/stuoq3f5/

Comment: If new Option creates an HTMLOptionElement, you can attach it to 1 parent node. So you must duplicate it instead: `showSelect.append(option.cloneNode())` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the cloneNode(true) with deep cloning because what is happening is that you are creating an option then appending it to noShowSelect, then to showSelect removing it from noShowSelect.

```
                   $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    let option = new Option(key, value);
                    $(option).html(value);
                    noShowSelect.append(option.cloneNode(true));
                    showSelect.append(option.cloneNode(true));
                    subscriptionSelect.append(option.cloneNode(true));
                });
```

Comment: Check the answers about copying by reference compared to by value.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value#:~:text=Javascript%20is%20always%20pass%20by,a%20new%20primitive%20or%20object.

Comment: Very nice :) . I suspected as such, but wanted confirmation which you now have given me. Thank you very mcuh

Answer (score 0):

You can select all "select" elements and append the options:

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    let option = new Option(key, value);
    $(option).html(value);
    $('select').append(option);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stuoq3f5/)

Comment: Hey Carlos : that is true (and was the solution I'm going with), thank you. However, I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why this isn't working.